# How to accept jdk's license agreement in command line?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, wget, java-7

I tried to install jdk7 (Linux x64 rpm) on to my Amazon EC2 instance. I used wget and curl -o to do so but it did not download successfully. Instead, it downloaded an error html file wherein it tells to accept the license agreement before downloading.
I used this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html to accept the agreement after which I right clicked on the package and copied the link and tried downloading it through command line, but it did not work.
I downloaded it to my local machine and used scp to move it on to my local directory in EC2. But when I tried executing it, it threw these errors :

```
sudo rpm -i jdk-7u7-linux-x64.rpm
Unpacking JAR files...
rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/rt.pack
jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/jsse.pack
charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/charsets.pack
tools.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/tools.pack
localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/ext/localedata.pack
```

I googled for a solution and came across this link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html

Even though it says :
"1. Download the file. Before the file can be downloaded, you must accept the license agreement." is there any way of accepting the license through command line?

Thank you!

I don't think this issue is caused by a problem accepting the license agreement (that is just to download), I think this is related to a buggy rpm package.  Post this rpm -i install, does java work? Can you navigate to /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/bin and run java?

Comment: The rpm package was fine. I wasn't able to download the jdk directly using the terminal and instead was trying to scp from my local machine to my Amazon instance. Probably scp didn't do a good job. Nevertheless, the solution posted below worked just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not you, it is the Oracle site.  They changed their licensing strategy.

Read this [blog post](http://blog.kdecherf.com/2012/04/12/oracle-i-download-your-jdk-by-eating-magic-cookies/) for more information, and some tips on automating it.

An interesting tidbit at the bottom of the post:

> According to the OTN BCL document for Java SE:
>
> BY SELECTING THE “ACCEPT LICENSE AGREEMENT” (OR THE EQUIVALENT) BUTTON
>   **AND/OR BY USING THE SOFTWARE** YOU ACKNOWLEDGE THAT YOU HAVE READ THE
>   TERMS AND AGREE TO THEM.

Comment: Yes that skirts the license issue, but it doesn't solve the "could not open input file" issue.

Comment: @ctpenrose - you have to follow the steps in the blog post to solve the "could not open input file".

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm. How the blogger would have find this? Amazing :)

Comment: Well I was encountering the same issue: I was unable to download the file from a server. It was really annoying so I checked what happened in the browser [when accepting the license] with the help of developer tools :-) As a side-note: http://le.kdecherf.com/post/21207105768/le-me-installing-jdk-on-three-servers

Answer (score 7):

For me it worked the following

```
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u40-b26/jdk-8u40-linux-x64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=yippi ka yei madafaka;" http://download.oracle.com/blahblah....
```

You can send anything you want as cookie value for "gpw_e24"

P.D: Excuse my poor english, trying my best ;-)